# Python Finding words after and before variable keyword while having commas and spaces in between

Tags: python, regex

My string is

```
string =  "Amtsgericht Berlin HRB 25665"
```

How can I find the word before AND after the keyword `HRB`?

This way I get the word after my keyword:

```
match = re.compile(r'HRB\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){1})')
print(match.findall(string))

>>>>> ['25665']
```

How can I add the keyword (`HRB`) as a variable into my regex expression?

Comment: Please can you show exactly what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(\w+)` to match words and format the keyword using f-string:

```
import re


string =  "Amtsgericht Berlin, HRB 25665"

KEYWORD = 'HRB'

match = re.compile(f'(\w+)[,|\s]*{KEYWORD}[,|\s]*(\w+)')

# [('Berlin', '25665')]
print(match.findall(string))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. How would you change the regex, if the string would be `` "Amtsgericht Berlin, HRB 25665"``? Very similar, but with a comma in between

Comment: @PParker Improved answer for you :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Very helpful for me!!!